# Laravel 5 - Como utilizar primary key em pivot table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tenho uma dúvida que surgiu agora. Deu uma buscada nos fóruns, e não achei nada parecido. Tenho esse esquema no meu BD:

users:
id
name
...

products:
id
name
...

product_user:
id
product_id
user_id
...

No meu User.php, tenho:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Láááá na minha view, tenho uma instância de User:
    @foreach($user->products as $product)
        // some code here...
    @endforeach

Mas, não consigo pegar o id da minha pivot table, assim:

```
@foreach($user->products as $product)
    {{ $product->pivot->id }}}
@endforeach
```

Até consigo pegar os outros campos, como por exemplo:=
    {{ $product->pivot->created_at }}}

Mas o id, não consigo. Quando dou um dd() em $product->pivot, e vejo os attributes, tenho isto:

```
#attributes: array:4 [▼
    "user_id" => 2
    "product_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2015-03-14 20:25:09"
    "updated_at" => "2015-03-14 20:25:09"
  ]
```

Como pego esse bendito ID da pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withTimestamps()->withPivot("id");
}
```